# Does the PPA occur in a periphrastic form?

Tags: conjugation, participle, esse

***Can you put a PPA in a periphrastic construction, with a form of esse?***

I was working on the periphrastic declension of the future active parts and the future passive parts. Now it occurred to me: Would there also be such declension with PPA's, in combination with the forms of esse?

**PPA + praesens esse**
Cantans sum. - I'm singing.
Cantans sim. - May I be singing.

**PPA + perfectum esse**
Cantans fui. - I've been singing.
Ne cantans fueris. - Don't be singing.

**PPA + imperfectum esse**
Cantans eram. - I was singing.
Utinam cantans essem. - If only I were singing.

**PPA + plusquamperfectum esse**
Cantans fueram. - I had been singing.
Utinam cantans fuissem. - If only I had been singing.

**PPA + futurum simplex esse**
Cantans ero. - I will be singing.

**PPA + futurum perfectum esse**
Cantans fuero. - I will have been singing.

**PPA + present infinitive esse**
Cantans esse. - To be singing.

**PPA + perfectum infinitive esse**
Cantans fuisse. - To have been singing.

Are all these sequences (using *cantans* as an example) possible to say? And do they also occur (especially the *PPA + praesens esse*)? And is there perhaps also a *participle + future infinitive esse*, such as *cantans futurum esse* or *cantans fore*?

Comment: What is a PPA? Participle present active?

Comment: Yeah, can you clarify what you mean? Quick answer, though, is that no, these are not correct in Classical Latin.

Comment: Johannes, we also have answered a question like this before. If you feel that thread doesn't answer your question fully, feel free to edit yours for clarity and to specify what further questions you might have.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I second the comment by @cmw and I added a number of similar questions to the list. I recommend that you take a look at those other questions and see whether they contain the answer to yours. If not, please edit to clarify your question in relation to the other ones and their answers. There can well be an excellent original question in there, but it needs some distilling.